# UAVs and using ground control

Tags: australia, photogrammetry, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, ground-control

I have been having a conversation at the office about whether to use ground control when using drones/UAVs to capture aerial images. The ground control that I am referring too is any [permanent survey markers](https://www.business.qld.gov.au/industry/titles-property-construction/surveying/permanent-survey-marks), or [Real Time kinematic systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Kinematic) that would aid in improving the spatial accuracy of the data captured. I would imagine that the level of ground control you would use, would depend on the accuracy that you were trying to achieve.

Would anyone know if there are some guidelines or provide some advice, for the use of ground control within Australia, when conducting an aerial surveys (UAVs) for use within photogrammetry?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Australian flight regulations have no relation to Geographic Information Systems.

Comment: The whole UAV thing is ahead of regulations, even CASA doesn't have firm guidelines except for 'don't get dangerous' rules. Ground control is a *really* good idea to at least measure the accuracy of the data (at least one inside) but I know of no regulations that would enforce their use. Obviously the more control the better the accuracy and that would be between you and your client as to whether a visual or accurate dataset is required.

Comment: @Vince. The use of survey techniques to acquire accuracy would be related to gis. UAV are a platform for remotely sensed imagery which is what the ground control is needed for.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson, Totally agree with having the ground control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For ground control, you're going to want something easily visible from your UAV. Temporary GCPs may be good enough for your purposes. Personally, I've used weighted plywood painted with an arrow in bright colors like yellow and red. The tip of the arrow gives you a precise location to both set your RTK unit over and visually identify when georeferencing later with ArcMap or Postflight Terra 3D or whichever software you choose.

If you can find multiple survey markers that are easily visible beneath your flight path, I don't see any problems with using those, as long as they're spread out over the area. However, you might not get so lucky. Circumstances permitting, you could create your own permanent ground control points. If you're going to do several flyovers of the same area and you can get the permission of whoever owns the land, you can spray paint a paved area or embed concrete blocks into the dirt and paint these.